# Fedora 28 ACPI BIOS error

Tags: fedora, boot, acpi, radeon

I have fedora 28 and windows as dual boot but after updating some packages in fedora my machine now won't boot. I also can't boot into recovery mode as the same problem persists. These are the error messages, can anyone please explain how to resolve this issue without wiping my machine?

[image]

Comment: Pretty much all solutions involves upgrading your BIOS when you have this kind of "fatal" ACPI error with AE_NOT_FOUNT - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=491588 - Is there a way you could boot Windows and make the BIOS upgrade?(or create a FreeDOS USB disk and upgrade your bios as pointed out by some Dell hardware documentation)...

Comment: I have booted from Windows, updated the BIOS and tried to boot from Fedora but the same error is present. I will have a look at trying to to create a FreeDOS USB disk.

Comment: I just updated by BIOS using the FreeDOS USB disk and it has changed nothing. My BIOS is now 2.8.1

Comment: And the message about the ACPI error remains the same? You could also check if there is something wrong with this last `radeon` module update by editing your grub entry before boot and adding `modprobe.blacklist=radeon` at the end of the `linux` line - https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f27/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader.html

Comment: Yes the error remains the same. I have just followed those steps and now it only has the first 4 errors in the above picture. The radeon related errors are gone.

Comment: `radeon` errors are gone after blacklisting it but it is still not booting, right?

Comment: Next measure i would take to debug this(based on an old notebook that i had with acpi problems) is to completely disable acpi at boot with the `acpi=off`kernel parameter on grub...

Comment: Okay so after putting `acpi=off modprobe.blacklist-radeon` at the end of the linux line, there are now no errors on the screen but it just remains black. It seems like it doesn't even try to boot as the fedora logo doesn't come up.

Comment: If those errors are different than those at the current image, please post them as a second image of this question explaining the changes you've made so we can better help :)

Comment: The screen is just blank when i boot using `acpi=off modprobe.blacklist=radeon` on the linux line. No errors are on the screen but the machine does not boot.

Comment: Any chance you could reveal basic specs of your system? Looking at the screen we can only know that is a Dell one but not sure if it's a desktop or a notebook. Give us the model of your equipment and also, try to replace the `acpi=off` parameter with `pci=noacpi`, since the first line seems to show an acpi error at pci0.

Comment: Yes of course, I have a Dell Precision Tower 3420. When I used `pci=noacpi modprobe.blacklist=radeon` new errors showed - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgszj.jpg

Comment: @nwildner I hvae a Dell precision tower 3420 with an Intel Core i7-7700 CPU with 3.60 GHz. Also i've just noticed in my BIOS in my PCI information my slot 1 is "empty" and my slot 2 is "VGA Compatible". Would this be the problem?

Comment: No problem at all. Do you have any hardware attached to PCI1 ? I'm searching for more ACPI+BIOS+Fedora+Your_hardware info on different sites and the best answers i could find is "use Ubuntu 18.04 that is better supported by Dell"... LOL

Comment: @nwildner I decided to wipe my machine today rather than continue to find an error. Everything is working fine now, thanks for all your help.